# Apache beam read csv file and groupbykey

Tags: python, json, group-by, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a csv file, I know how to achieve this by using `pandas`, basically read csv as a `df` -> group the data by field `'aaa', 'bbb'and then construct a new 'id'.

My question is how can I achieve the same with `Apache Beam`, I've never used it before, I'm trying to use Beam to read this csv file and group multiple records, but the exact same functionality I used with pandas doesn't support Beam, the following is my current code:

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.dataframe.io import read_csv

pipeline = beam.Pipeline()
csv_lines = (pipeline | 'ReadFile' >> beam.io.ReadFromText('xxx.csv')
| ???? )
```

My question is:

- How can I perform data manipulation when there's no header after using `beam.io.ReadFromText()`
- What's the best way to achieve the same thing with Beam as I described above (group multiple records and construct a new id, then convert it to json)

Hope this makes sense, I'm new to Beam, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're able to do it with Pandas, you should be able to do it with the [Beam Dataframes API](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/) in exactly the same way.

To do this with Beam directly, you can map your rows into 2-tuples, where the first element is the key (`'postcode', 'property_type','old/new','PAON'` in your case) and then use [GroupByKey](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#groupbykey) to group things together.  For example, suppose your element is a dictionary with the above keys, i.e. the elements of your input PCollection are dictionaries

```
{'postcode': ..., 'property_type': ..., 'old/new': ..., 'PAON': ..., ...}
```

Then you could write

```
def get_key(property_dict):
  return (
      property_dict['postcode'],
      element['property_type'], 
      element['old/new'], 
      element['PAON'])
      

grouped = (
    input_pcoll
    | beam.Map(lambda element: (get_key(element), element))
    | beam.GroupByKey())
```